# R.java variable is already defined in class dimen, Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, r.java-file

I am fetching a float value, (lets call it float_val) from dimens.xml There are multiple copies of dimens file which are present in values, values-hdpi, values-mdpi etc.

I am using Gradle. Gradle gives an error for this. R.java:1944: error: variable float_var is already defined in class dimen.

It seems, that Gradle is trying to put the same variable defined in different dimens.xml files in a single R.java file. What should I do to solve it?

Comment: maybe you added the same dimen in the same file? check it.

Comment: I checked. There is only one occurrence of this variable in dimens.xml of each of the values, values-hdpi and values-mdpi folders.

Comment: really frustrated with similar problem, how did you solve it?